# What does the phrase "it wouldn't take" mean in this context?

Tags: phrase-meaning

An episode of *Seinfeld* has the following dialogue:

> GEORGE: "What day is today? Oh... Tuesday! Damn it. I shouldn't have
>   worked out today. Mr. Wilhem has called a big meeting and now I'm
>   gonna be sweating through the whole thing."
>
> JERRY: "Why, you took a shower?"
>
> GEORGE: "Argh... **it wouldn't take**." [Audience laughter]

Can someone clarify what this means (and why it is funny?). Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

He means that he continued to be hot and sweaty even after the shower.  The shower had no effect on him, so he might as well not have taken one.

Merriam-Webster defines this sense of "take" as "to take effect : to show the natural or intended effect".

It's a maxim of comedy that one should never explain why a joke is funny, but likely some in the audience laughed because they had experienced exactly this situation in their own lives, and they found George's line a succinct, pithy, and accurate representation of the experience.  Others might laugh because they had *never* experienced this, and thus it seems ridiculous to them that George is "immune" to showers.

Comment: Interesting, I haven't heard the word used in that sense before.